# VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://xxxxx-tfs

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines, build-agent

I'm getting following error when try to configure the build agent. Following is the commands I used, Please advice how to resolve this.

```
C:\agent>config

>> Connect:

Enter server URL > https://xxxx-tfs-1
Enter authentication type (press enter for Integrated) >
Connecting to server ...

>> Register Agent:

Enter agent pool (press enter for default) >
Enter agent name (press enter for xxxx-TFS-1) >
Scanning for tool capabilities.
Connecting to the server.
Enter replace? (Y/N) (press enter for N) > y
Successfully replaced the agent
Testing agent connection.
VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://xxxx-tfs-1.
```

Comment: Does the build agent machine join into the same domain as the TFS server?

Answer (score 7):

It’s usually caused by **Anonymous Authentication** is disabled.

On your TFS server -> Internet Information Services (IIS) manager -> Authentication -> change **Anonymous Authentication** is enabled.

[image]

Comment: What is Anonymous Authentication can not be enabled per company security policies. How do you get around this?