# What is the appropriate agent setup on an Azure Devops on premise server with disabled anonymous authentication?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server

I have an on-prmise Azure Devops installation. Due to company security policies we need to disable Anonymous Authentication in IIS for the devops portal. However this causes the agents to go offline. I have played with installing the agents with the different authentication options during configuration with no success. What is the recommended agent setup when anonymous authentication is disabled?

This is related to this question where the answer suggests to enable anonymous authentication, what if this is not an option:
[VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://xxxxx-tfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42651532/vs30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-https-xxxxx-tfs)

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer from Microsoft team regarding this. It turns out Anonymous Authentication is required by desing on this scenario.

*"By product design, IIS anonymous authentication is required for OAuth authentication to work. This OAuth authentication is being used by azure devops for the agent and pipeline functionality, for this reason even if we have agents already configured, those agents will become unusable if we disable the Anonymous authentication."*

Security shouldn't be of concern either....
*"azure devops product already have an excellent security approach for that.
The TFS/azure devops server application in IIS will not let unauthenticated requests through.  That just lets it through the IIS front door to the application which enforces OAuth.
For example, in a pipeline run, the build server generates an OAuth token *per* build which is scoped to the build and expires after the build.  So even though the token is guarded, if leaked, it's useless after the build - contrary to an identity.  The OAuth token is also not available to code run by the build process (unit tests checked in by developers).  If it relied on the windows identity the windows service ran as, then developers running unit tests in the CI could elevate to access or delete code they don't have permissions to."*